# Folder /Home is almost full with only one user. Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: partitioning, 20.04, permissions, root, home-directory

I just started in this "wonderful" world of Linux

So I installed Ubuntu 20.04 in my laptop with some partitions

- Boot
- Swap
- Home
- /

But today I figured out something strange.

Folder home was full due to some files and other stuff that I'm working.

But as far as I know. If you only has one user and in this case is my user and obviously with more permissions.
All of data will save in root folder not in home folder.

Maybe is a "new feature" of Ubuntu 20.04 ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't know where you got that information from. It's completely wrong. Any user's data is always saved in its user area, not in the root filesystem which is ONLY for the OS and software, even most software *settings* are save per user in their own folders. So, probably, you manual partitioning stemmed from your misconception and, probably, has a huge root that transalates in a huge waste of space and clearly an insufficient /home.

Comment: Additional info: You don't need a separated /boot nor, currently, a separated /swap. Ubuntu now uses a dynamic swapfile by default.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. For someone who just started, you shouldn't have created all these partitions. Please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1360070/edit) and add more information about your partition scheme. Install Gparted and take a screenshot of the app's window. Upload the screenshot in imagur.com. Add a link to the uploaded image in your question. Then we can see what you have done in terms of the partitions.

Comment: @ChanganAuto  Oh I see. So I should change the partitions and set more Gbs to home instead of root folder ( now this folder has almost all the disk size ‍♂️)

Comment: Could you please edit your question with the output of `df -h` ?

Comment: for normal use 20Gb for / is more than enough. /home can have anything else. If you want more flexibility: 20Gb for / and /home and the remainder on a user mount (something like /discworld) and put personal files on there (full reinstall then means: format / and /home and mount user partition)

Comment: If you create partitions in advance, you have to use Something Else and choose (change button) both the partition as you want as / (root) and the one you want as /home. If your fstab is not mounting the partition you thought would be /home, you can move your /home data & then add entry in fstab to auto mount it. To move /home uses rsync- Be sure to use parameters to preserve ownership & permissions 
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Partitioning/Home/Moving